# Substring error using lastIndexOf in Java

Tags: java

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  

    System.out.print("Enter your range (Ex. 1 - 10): ");
    String range = in.nextLine();

    String lowerRange = range.substring(0, range.indexOf(" "));
    **String upperRange = range.substring(range.lastIndexOf(" "));**

    int lowerRangeInt = Integer.parseInt(lowerRange);
    int upperRangeInt = Integer.parseInt(upperRange);
```

I need the user to enter the two numbers to be the ranges and needed it to be on the same line, so I used the in.nextLine and was going to separate the first range from the 0 index till the first index of a space, giving me the lower range, and the upper range I intended to use the last index of a space to give me the upper range.

My error comes at **String upperRange = range.substring(range.lastIndexOf(" "));** saying there is an extra space when it trys to covert it to an int.

Comment: what is input and expected result? what is the error you get?

Comment: You are assuming that the user will place a space within the output and not do something like `5-9` ;)

Comment: Well have u used spilt for this??

Comment: You could also use `String upperRange = range.substring(range.lastIndexOf(" ")).trim();` to trim off any leading/trailing spaces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
String upperRange = range.substring(range.lastIndexOf(" "));
```

to

```
String upperRange = range.substring(range.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1 , range.length);
```

Comment: for love of god, do you care to write some explantion so we can learn something?!!!

Comment: String upperRange = range.substring(range.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1); worked, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get rid of extra space, you could call `trim()` on your `String`. But, I would use [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to do it in one step. Split on the whitespace. The first token is the lower-range, and the last token is the upper range (any thing in the middle is a separator). Something like,

```
String[] values = range.split("\\s+");
int lowerRangeInt = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
int upperRangeInt = Integer.parseInt(values[values.length - 1]);
```

Comment: I believe you should help the op first to solve it's issue and after that you can have suggestion at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
String lowerRange = range.substring(0, range.indexOf(" "));
```

works because the beginning index (`0`) is inclusive (returned with the result) and the end index (`range.indexOf(" ")`) is *not*

taking that into consideration when looking at

```
String upperRange = range.substring(range.lastIndexOf(" "));
```

should tell us that the beginning index (`range.lastIndexOf(" ")`) *is* inclusive and therefore will be included in the response. This is where your space is coming from.

Simple solution is to shift it up by 1 with `range.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1`